# Cant add multiple strings to variable

Tags: python

I have a problem i am trying to make morse
decoder, and want to add two same strings to
one variable, but it always add only one but the other disappeared. [picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQjQY.jpg) and code can be found below:

```
print("type something in morse")
choice = input()
choice = choice.replace("/", " ")
times = 0
final = ""
val1 = ""
val2 = ""
val3 = ""
val4 = ""


def stringToList(string):
    ListRes = list(string.split("/"))
    return ListRes


strA = choice
in_list = stringToList(choice)
long = len(in_list) - 1

for i in range(long):
    letter = in_list[times]
    if letter == ".-":
        val1 = "a"
    elif letter == "-...":
        val2 = "b"
    elif letter == "-.-.":
        val3 = "c"
    elif letter == "-..":
        val4 = "d"

    times = times + 1
final = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4
print(final)
```

Comment: Post your code as *text*, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store them as a list of strings, and concatenate each string to the list.

```py
string1 = 'foo'
string2 = 'bar'

strings = []

strings += string1
strings += string2

print(strings)
# ['foo', 'bar']

# use indexing to get each string
print(strings[0])
# 'foo'

print(strings[1])
# 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your program works, there are some parts missing I think.
If you want to look up a code, the easiest way is to use a dictionary:

```
    morse = {'.-': 'a', 
             '-...': 'b', 
             '-.-.': 'c', 
             '-..': 'd'} # Complete yourself!}
    inp = input("Code: ")

    if inp in morse:
       print('decoded:', morse[inp])
    else:
       print('cannot find [', inp, '] in table')
```

Example run:

```
Code: -.-.
decoded: c
```

or

```
Code: --..
cannot find [ --.. ] in table
```